# EACCESS Permissioin Denied

Tags: npm, npm-install, permission-denied, flowise

im trying to get flowise on my mac m1, but in order to finish the set up i need yarn. i use the "cd flowise", then "install yarn". but it says i need to enable corepack, so i do, but when i use "corepack enable". Then it gives me EACES permission denied error.

So i followed the instructions here https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Then i tried re-installing npm with node.js.

Sill permission denied. So I used the manual method mentioned in that link, but when i get to "source ~/.profile" command it says no such file. Theres definetely a file with that name, but i made it from the text edit file so idk if thats wrong.

so i cant install flowise because i need yarn, but to get yarn i need to move npm so it can have proper permission, but i cant move it because the "source ~/.profile" command returns "no such file..."

Any ideas?

i mentioned in the previous section